# R - Como dividir polígono em partes iguais

Tags: r

Tenho um polígono formado pelo vértices

```
> ver
  id      x       y
1  1 806648 9719778
2  2 806887 9719588
3  3 797995 9710368
4  4 797745 9710547
```

quando ploto sai a seguinte imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou seja , seria um polígono tipo esse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de dividi-lo em partes iguais e extrair os vértices para ter um conjunto de pontos. O polígono teria que ficar como esse abaixo (ta um pouco errado, pois desenhei manualmente, não ficando simétrico)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que significa exatamente "partes iguais"? "Partes iguais" significam áreas idênticas? Ou a forma destas "partes iguais" deve ser sempre a mesma? O polígono será sempre um quadrilátero? Ou melhor: será sempre um retângulo? Os lados opostos deste quadrilátero são paralelos dois a dois? Por exemplo, não é trivial para mim visualizar como dividir um trapézio em 5 partes idênticas. Seja mais específico em sua pergunta que talvez alguém consiga ter uma ideia para te ajudar.

Comment: Minha área é um retângulo com largura de 300 metros e cumprimento de 12 km. Porém ele está com rotação de um angulo x, como representado na imagem acima. Gostaria de dividi-lo de tal maneira que a largura continuasse 300 m e o cumprimento com valores idênticos. Por exemplo 12 retângulos de 300 m de largura  x 1000 m de cumprimento. Sempre levando em conta que devo fazer isso para a angulação que ele segue.